# How to model a `UNIQUE` constraint in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a Flask/SQLAlchemy application in which I have users and groups.

Users can belong to several groups, and **they have a unique number within each group**. [Asking about how to model the database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/32961/how-to-model-a-user-group-relationship-where-users-are-assigned-an-unique-number/32965#32965) I was advised to use the following table structure for my many-to-many relationship:

```
TABLE UserGroups
  GroupID 
  UserID
  UserNumber
  PRIMARY KEY (GroupID, UserID)
  UNIQUE (GroupID, UserNumber)
  FOREIGN KEY (GroupID)
    REFERENCES Groups (GroupID)
  FOREIGN KEY (UserID)
    REFERENCES Users (UserID)
```

Now I know how to create a regular many-to-many relationship with SQLAlchemy, but I don't know how to represent the `UNIQUE` constraint with the additional `UserNumber` field.

I don't have a lot of experience with database design, ORMs and SQLAlchemy, so this may be obvious, but I can't find a way to express it.

On of the things I don't get is: using a regular many-to-many relationship, my `User` class has a *list-like* attribute `groups` which contains all the groups he belongs to, but this completely hides the `UserGroups` joining-table and I don't know how to access the `UserNumber` field.

This is all a bit blur to me. Do you have any good example or explanations on how-to do such a thing with SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: Will someone edit the question title to reflect what's being asked more specifically?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first part of the question (about creating a unique constraint with multiple columns) is already [answered by cleg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14355621/851737).

However, the default many-to-many approach doesn't work if you want to have additionally columns in the mapping table. Instead, you should use the [Association Object Pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#association-object). Additionally, you can simplify the access between user and group with an [association_proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects).

The [`proxied_association.py`](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/master/examples/association/proxied_association.py) from the [SQLAlchemy examples](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/examples.html#associations) should be a good place to start.

Answer (score 23):

For people that, like me, came here to just find a working snippet to set unique contraint:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, UniqueConstraint

Base = declarative_base()

class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "model"

    model_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # will create "model_num_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (num)
    num = Column(Integer, unique=True)
    # same with UniqueConstraint:
    num2 = Column(Integer)
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("num2", name="model_num2_key"),)
    # for multiple columns:
    # __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("num", "num2", name="two_columns"),)
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `UniqueConstraint` in your model. In detailed it's described in this question: [sqlalchemy unique across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059345/sqlalchemy-unique-across-multiple-columns)

As for many-to-many relations, SQLAlchemy have [pretty good tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-many-to-many-relationship).

P.S. Sorry, I've missed with second part of answer (it's more complex then I've thought, so see answer from @schlamar), but first part is still correct.

Comment: The default many-to-many approach doesn't work if you want to have additionally columns in the mapping table.

Comment: I wrote my answer before seen @schlamar, but now added a reference.

Comment: It's not the matter of repo, just want to be honest :)